# Cannot connect to Internet through WIFI though WIFI signal is excellent

Tags: wireless-networking, ipad

I just bought an IPAD. I have also an iphone.

I connected to a wifi network successfully for both.

I can browse internet with my iphone but on my ipad it says I am not connected to Internet !

Is my Ipad broken or did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you connected with both then say that one says its  is not connected so I assume you never connected with one of them.

Excuse me Im just trying to help you but I am a fairly new IPOD TOUCH user and old IBM and medocer (my spelling is terrible also) user but sounds like to me that the units likely have different firmware (Obvious since the pad must be different from the phone or touch.

Check on the one that is logging in correctly, write down what security it uses (if any,, you didnt say) Here is what I feel may have happened. Its possible you failed to log out with the origonal unit. Therefore you may have reached the preprogrammed max users and it want let you log in.

If not see if your system is using WPA one might have an "auto" option the other you might have the specify TKIP or AES . If you fail to specify the proper AES or TKIP you will not log in.

Im shooting in the dark but just in case is there power settings on your two "DIFFERENT" units? Maybe you have the power turned to low on one?

nothing personal but i hate questions like yours where you ommit so many things that we could use to help you more precisely.

lastly you may be or have selected security when it is an open system. these computers can drive u nuts on occasion.

also if you have an account that has recorded your mac number (its an id number like a car has a tag number but issued by the fcc to identify the manfactureer etc.

it almost sounds like to me that you experianced being connected via both your units TO ONE WAP POINT then went out to a different wap unit and couldnt login one the second.

When your in those places where you pay for using like say you buy a hambuger and it gives you 30 minutes. Once you login "THE FIRST TIME" with the mac via the first unit, security will not allow you to log in again with a diffrent unit. After all you may have been on the bank and paid some bills then loged out or DIDNT LOG OUT and assumed you could log in with your other unit. The other unit could be owned by a crook or an identity theft stealer. The system does you a favor an lets no other mac addreses into the system.

Darned what a complicated answer I gave you. NOPE dont go throw away the unit that failed to connect. Sound like your vendor was protecting your security to me.

You might have loggin in at home or a buddies house the first time and he doesnt have any rules on mac numbers so you logged in with same name and password.

I hope you understand that when you post a simply question you must post a lot of extra data in order to get a precise perfect answer.

Good luck

Comment: Oh my what a lengthy answer :) Ok don't mind I'm now pretty sure something is broken with my ipad so I'll go to the apple store directly for them to repair.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to make sure that you typed in any necessary credentials to authenticate yourself for the wireless access point? Comment to answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have plenty time to spare (as I do)  I feel your pad is simply fine. The problem you describe will be encountered from time to time and you will learn what to look for and how to deal with it as needed.

Continue to use it, it seems as if it worked initially although Im a bit unsure you will likely fall in love with it once you learn its idiosyncrasies

Coley